# TypeScript inferring first array element from the second array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have a variable `arr` that is either type `[number, 'number']` or `[null, 'null']`. Is it possible to infer the type of `arr[0]` based on the value of `arr[1]`? Here is the issue, I don't think my use case works with function overloads since the value of `arr[1]` is a side effect of the function returning it. Instead of `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` I'm using the following names `data` and `status` to represent those values respectively. In this case, `data` would be the data I'm trying to fetch from my API, and `status` is the status (idle, pending, success, or error) of the API request.

I'm thinking of `useFetch` as a state machine. Basically, I'm trying to have it infer the type of the machine context (`data`) from the state (`status`) of the machine. I thought about digging into XState's source code cause I think they do something similar to this. See [XStates docs](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/typescript.html#typestates).

I have the following React hook. See the `useFetch` function below:

```js
export declare namespace FetchUtil {
  export type Status = 'idle' | 'pending' | 'error' | 'success'

  export type Response<Data, Status> = Readonly<[Data, Status]>

  export namespace States {
    export type Idle = null
    export type Pending = null
    export type Error = { messgage: string }
    export type Success<T> = T
  }
}

interface Config extends Omit<RequestInit, 'body'> {
  body?: Record<string, any>
}

export async function fetchUtil<T> (url: string, config?: Config): Promise<T | null> {
  let args: RequestInit = {}

  const { body, ...restConfig } = config ?? {}
  
  if (body) {
    args.body = JSON.stringify(body)
  }
  
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    cache: 'no-cache',
    ...restConfig,
    ...args,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      ...restConfig.headers,
      ...args.headers,
    }
  })

  if (response.status >= 400) {
    const { error } = await response.json()
    throw new Error(error ?? 'failed to fetch')
  }

  return await response.json()
}

interface UseFetchConfig extends Config {
  enabled?: boolean
}

export function useFetch<T>(url: string, config?: UseFetchConfig) {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState<FetchUtil.Status>('idle')
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<T | FetchUtil.States.Error>()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setStatus('idle')
    if (config?.enabled === false) {
      return
    }
    setStatus('pending')

    fetchUtil<T>(url, config)
    .then(res => {
      if (res !== null) {
        setData(res)
        setStatus('success')
      } else {
        setData({
          messgage: 'not found'
        })
        setStatus('error')  
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      setData(err)
      setStatus('error')
    })
  }, [url, config?.enabled])

  switch (status) {
    case 'idle':
      return [null, status] as FetchUtil.Response<FetchUtil.States.Idle, typeof status>
    case 'pending':
      return [null, status] as FetchUtil.Response<FetchUtil.States.Pending, typeof status>
    case 'success':
      return [data, status] as FetchUtil.Response<FetchUtil.States.Success<T>, typeof status>
    case 'error':
      return [data, status] as FetchUtil.Response<FetchUtil.States.Error, typeof status>
  }
}
```

And I can use the hook like so:

```
function Tweet({ id }) {
  const [tweet, status] = useFetch<API.Tweet>(urls.api(`/tweets/${id}`))

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'idle') {
      // TS should infer that type of tweet is FetchUtil.States.Idle
    }

    else if (status === 'pending') {
      // TS should infer that type of tweet is FetchUtil.States.Pending
    }

    else if (status === 'success') {
      // TS should infer that type of tweet is FetchUtil.States.Success<API.Tweet>
    }
    
    else if (status === 'error') {
      // TS should infer that type of tweet is FetchUtil.States.Error
    }
  }, [tweet, status])

  // ...
}
```

The issue is TS is not detecting the type of `tweet` based on the type of `status`. Is it possible to infer the type of the first array item based on the type of the second array item? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will use the example at the top instead of the one at the bottom; you can apply it there if you want.

Say you have the following union of tuples type:

```
type Arr = [number, 'number'] | [null, 'null'];
```

Such a union is considered a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions); the property at index `1` is the *discriminant* because you can use it to tell which member of the union a value satisfies.  (Such discrimination only works when the property you check is of a unit type: that is, a type to which only one value is assignable: like `"number"` or `123` or `true` or `undefined` or `null`, but not `number` or `string`.)

That means you should indeed be able to narrow a value `arr` of type `Arr` to the appropriate member of the union by checking `arr[1]`:

```
function f(arr: Arr) {
  switch (arr[1]) {
    case "null": {
      const [data, status] = arr;
      return "It's null";
    }
    case "number": {
      const [data, status] = arr;
      return data.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that what you *cannot* do is to destructure `arr` into `data` and `status` *before* you do this check.  That's because once you do this, `data` and `status` will each be seen by the compiler as *uncorrelated* union types.  It will know that `data` is `number | null` and that `status` is `"number" | "null"`, but it has no way to keep track of the fact that `data` cannot be `null` if `status` is `"number"`.  The discriminated union nature has been lost.

While it would be nice if there were some way for the compiler to represent correlated unions, and while I have filed an issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581),  wishing for such a thing,  it's not likely to be possible in TypeScript for the foreseeable future. Instead, I'd suggest the workaround above: where you check `arr[1]` directly, and then destructure if you need to afterward, once per each scope in which `arr` has been narrowed.  It's redundant, but at least the compiler can verify type safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBtAdgVwLYCMJwA0UA5FngSQLpQA+aWANo8WZs9QNwBQ3AZpnQBjYAEsA9uih8AFAEMEALlgIAlFADe3KFADOAd1HAhACyjyEqAIxV1WnTqFzd0AERNGr5fYePJu4DQAEzlgOWIA0MxdGhQFOB5fHTgIYEw4KVcASWASXSgPV0SHAF9tBycXKHccfDgvTXLfIX9A1BCwiLC0mOQoeOLfFLSMqA65ADpgcQAxUQAPCCCZACZVQagynTKy-hlrFYBmYhqKettOKAB6K6hxAGs5ED2MdhZqwovr24enl6sjidPutvlACHBxHAgA)